# How to get MSMessage summary text from Received Message?

Tags: ios, swift3, imessage, ios-extensions, imessage-extension

I am passing summary message in MSMessage , but when try to get when message received at other end, it returns nil.

**Below is code for create Message**.

```
fileprivate func composeMessage(with url: String, andEventInfo eventInfo: NSDictionary?) -> MSMessage {

    let message = MSMessage(session:MSSession())
    message.url = URL(string: url)
    message.layout = createTemplateForEvent(eventInfo: eventInfo!)
    message.summaryText = "SAMPLE MESSAGE"
    return message
}
```

**To Send Message in Current Conversation**

```
let message = composeMessage(with: url!,andEventInfo: eventInfo)
    activeConversation?.insert(message, completionHandler: { (error) in

        print(error)
    })
```

**Now, At receiving end**

Here `summaryText` returns nil.

```
override func didReceive(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation) {

     print("DID RECEIVE MESSAGE: \(message.summaryText)")        
}
```

Also when user tap on message, then also it returns nil

```
override func willTransition(to presentationStyle: MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle) {
    guard let conversation = activeConversation else { fatalError("Expected an active converstation") }

    // Present the view controller appropriate for the conversation and presentation style.
    if presentationStyle == .expanded {

        if conversation.selectedMessage != nil {

            print(conversation.selectedMessage?.summaryText)

            presentViewController(for: conversation, with: presentationStyle)
        }

    }

}
```

Any one have idea, why this happens or any thing is going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May this will be helpful

```
override func didReceive(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation) {
// Called when a message arrives that was generated by another instance of this
// extension on a remote device.

// Use this method to trigger UI updates in response to the message.
guard let messageURL = message.url else { return }
guard let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(url: messageURL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false), let queryItems = urlComponents.queryItems else { return }

print("URL Components", urlComponents)
print("queryItems", queryItems)

for item in queryItems {
    print("Received \(item.name) with value \(item.value)")
}

}
```

Reference & helped Source: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/ios10

And Also Refer : [iOS10 iMessage : Unable to insert data into iMessage using MSConversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571141/ios10-imessage-unable-to-insert-data-into-imessage-using-msconversation/39792953#39792953)

Comment: Yea, queryItems works well to pass data of message using name and value pair. Thanks.